# How to assign to array without changing it dimensions in R (without S4)?

Tags: r, class, operator-overloading, variable-assignment

Assume that I have a following object:

```
X<-NULL
X$y<-1:10
X$A<-array(1:15,c(3,3,5))
attr(X,"Adim1")<-3
attr(X,"Adim2")<-5
class(X)<-"MyClass"
```

Now I would like to change the values of `X$A`, without the option to change it dimensions, i.e. **I would like `X$A` to have following properties**:

```
# This should work
    X$A<- array(1,c(3,3,5))
# This should give an error or be identical with  X$A[]<-4 i.e. X$A<- array(4,c(3,3,5))
    X$A<- 4 
#Actually it should be possible to change the last dimension to 1 but that's just some sugar:
    X$A<- array(1,c(3,3,1))
```

I'm wondering is this kind of behaviour something that could be done? I was thinking about giving x$A some class like "MyClassArray" and overload the assignment operator with appropriate checks, but with quick googling it seems that it is not recommended or even possible to overload "<-" operator. So are there any other options?

I know that it could be accomplished using S4 classes, but I do not want to mix S3 and S4.

Comment: it works fine for me `X$A <- 4` .what is the error you have? and why do you use `x` and `X` in the same example!

Comment: Yes X$A<-4 does not give error but I would like it to work so that it does give error or is identical to x$A[]<-4. Small x was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[<-`, like this:

```
X <- NULL
X$A <- array(1:15,c(3,3,5))
X$A[] <- 4
X


$A
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4
[3,]    4    4    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4
[3,]    4    4    4

... etc.
```

Comment: Yes that works but I want that kind of behaviour be default for that object.